# Is a Factory calling a Factory an anti-pattern or an extension of the Single Responsibility Principle?

Tags: single-responsibility, anti-patterns, factory

I'm busy playing around with some training material to help teach some of the juniors the factory pattern.

Whilst writing the example, I can't help but think this might be an anti-pattern.

Lets say I have `iVehicle` which is implemented by `iMotorVehicle` which, subsequently is implemented by `iCar`, `iBike` and `iTruck` respectively.

Would it be considered an anti-pattern to call a `VehicleFactory`, whose sole responsibility is to produce a resultant of `iVehicle` which will then call the `MotorVehicleFactory`, producing `iMotorVehicle` to call the `CarFactory` to produce a result of `iCar`?

To me this feels like each of the factories are fulfilling their respective responsibilities without stretching to fulfill a responsibility that could be fulfilled by another.

Is this an anti-pattern?

Comment: Related: https://danstroot.com/2018/10/03/hammer-factories/

Comment: @PieterB, “This thing comes with documentation, right?” That made me chuckle, thanks for that

Comment: Then the only you need is a single factory. Our you could turn VehicleFactory into an abstract factory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is basically the [abstract factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern), combined with the [facade pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern).

It is also something that follows logically when you iterate on abstracting away the creation of your vehicles. You start by abstracting away the fact that your `Car` needs an `Engine` and 4 instances of `Wheel` into a factory (and do the same for the other vehicles). Moving what is essentially a `switch` to select the correct `Factory` into a reusable layer it then a logical step.

Based on what you describe, *for this (most likely fictional) example*, I think it makes sense to add this layer. However (as [Pieter B pointed out](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/389766/is-a-factory-calling-a-factory-an-anti-pattern-or-an-extension-of-the-single-res#comment857841_389766)) it is important to find a good balance. A `FactoryFactory` is always a bad idea. A `DatabaseConnectionFactory` that selects the driver based on some input is usually a good idea. A key difference between the two is that a `FactoryFactory` will give you an intermediate, while a `DatabaseConnectionFactory` will clearly give you what you need - a `DatabaseConnection`.

So in summary, **no, your `VehicleFactory` is not an anti-pattern**.